# Finding correlated observations in very wide data

Tags: time-series, correlation, cross-correlation

Let us say we have an N x M matrix, where N are the number of records in time series data and M are columns containing observations for each period. What relatively efficient methods are available to find columns that are correlated, when N is in the thousands and M (the observations) may be in the tens of thousands? I'm aware that this problem may fall under 'cointegration'.

I am aware of some other posts on SO about correlation, but I'm focusing on the sheer size of the task here, with thousands of columns. Clearly an efficient algorithm is a starting point but beyond that, are there additional 'tricks' and methods that can reduce the problem space by orders of magnitude?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the naive solution complexity is `O(N * M^2)`

Since your question is very open I will go with PCA

1. You could start with your data creating a correlation matrix `O(N^2 * M)` (tens of times faster), if you assume some regularity you could compute this correlation using a random subset of the columns, possibly reducing one more order of magnitude.
2. Then you extract the eigenvectors associated with the largest eigenvalues. You can extract all of them with complexity `O(N^3)`, using SVD could be good for a partial decomposition.
3. Compute the `D x M` reduced dimension representation, with complexity `O(M * N * D)` (one correlation with each of the `D` principal components)
4. Do the pair search `O(M^2 * D)`, computing the correlations with complexity `O(D)` in your reduced dimension space.